# REST GET URL Naming

Tags: rest, aws-api-gateway

What is the best way to design or name an API URL that would get a specific user with a given unique identifier? I'm using `cognitoId` as the unique identifier.

Which of the following should I use?

1. /profiles/profile, then pass the cognitoId as URL Query String Parameters
2. /profiles/{id}
3. /profiles/profile then check 'Invoke with caller credentials'

Answer (score 0):

If it is an API where any authorized user can get anyone's username by passing a unique ID, then you could use something like this: /profiles/{id} For example, https://api.github.com/user/1

If it is an API that returns the username of the caller by using the cognito ID, then /profiles/profile should work. See $context.identity variables in [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#context-variable-reference) to fetch the cognito ID.

Comment: Made perfect sense! The authorised user should only get their own details.